# How to retrive single field array data from database and separate them- using laravel, PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-6

I Trying to upload multiple image for my product, and store the names of that images in database as an array.
My code works like this-

```
$images = $request->file('images');      

if (isset($images)) {
  foreach($images as $image){
    $imagename = $slug.'-'.$currentDate.'-'.uniqid().'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    if (!file_exists('uploads/product/images')) {
       mkdir('uploads/product/images', 0777, true);
    }
      $image->move('uploads/product/images', $imagename);
      $data[] = $imagename;
    }
            
  }else{
     $data[] = 'default.png';
  }

  $product = new Product();
  $product->images = json_encode($data);
```

And data stored inside the `images` field like-

```
["jeans-2020-08-13-5f352f18b30a4.jpg","jeans-2020-08-13-5f352f18b36a0.jpg","jeans-2020-08-13-5f352f18b3a2c.jpg"]
```

**And the problem is how can i separate this image name to show images in Laravel Blade? ** 
**OR** Suggest me, If there is another way to upload multiple image or multiple value in laravel-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deserialize the images names and then loop through them:

```
@foreach(json_decode($product->images) ?? [] as $image)
    <img src="uploads/product/images/{{ $image }}">
@endforeach
```